# Atata - Unable to locate element, using Table<> class

Tags: c#, selenium, atata

When I trying to refer to some element in table, using `Table<>` class, I get this error:

```
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element: By.XPath: .//td[1]/descendant-or-self::a
Context element:
Tag: tr
Location: {X=62,Y=273}
Size: {Width=1140, Height=37}
Text: Order Date User Address Origin Address Destination My Reference POD Status
```

A table source:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr class="text-nowrap">
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Address Origin</th>
        <th>Address Destination</th>
        <th>My Reference</th>
        <th>POD</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-nowrap">
                <a href="/Customer/Request/Show/180305-NQHHGU">180305-NQHHGU</a>
            </td>
            <td>05.03.2018</td>
            <td>Merchant Advance (2M7)</td>
            <td>Barry Manilow</td>
            <td>757 RUE GUY MONTREAL</td>
            <td>242 LAVERENDRYE AVE CHURCHILL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td class="text-nowrap">…</td>
        </tr>
```

Page object source:

```
public class OrdersPage : BasePage<_>
{
    public Table<OrdersTableRow, _> Orders { get; private set; }

    public class OrdersTableRow : TableRow<_>
    {
        [FindByColumnHeader("Order")]
        public LinkDelegate<ShipmentOrderPage, _> Order { get; private set; }

        public Date<_> Date { get; private set; }

        public Text<_> Customer { get; private set; }

        public Text<_> User { get; private set; }
        …
        …
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to do something like that in test:

```
    Go.To<OrdersPage>().
        Orders.Rows[x => x.Order.Content().Value == order.OrderNumber].Order();
```

I think it's about my table haven't `<thead>` tag. Have any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. Out of the box `Table` control works by default with `<table>` that contains `<th>` elements inside `thead/tr`. Such row is skipped when Atata handles regular/data rows.

You can check that `TableRow` class contains the following control definition:

```
[ControlDefinition("tr[parent::table or parent::tbody]", ComponentTypeName = "row")]
```

In your case the first row with headers was considered like a regular row, and Atata tried to find a link in this row, which is missing there.

But in Atata you can reconfigure such things easily. Just overwrite `[ControlDefinition]` of `OrdersTableRow` class as follows:

```
[ControlDefinition("tr[td]", ComponentTypeName = "row")]
public class OrdersTableRow : TableRow<_>
{
//...
}
```

This way `Orders.Rows` will process only `<tr>` elements that have `<td>` element inside, skipping the first row.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help!